# Format date in "M d, yy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to format `newDate` in format `Dec 24, 2013` which is currently like 
`Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530`

```
var dateString = 'Dec 17, 2013'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+7);

alert(dateString);

alert(newDate);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7eRXh/1/

Comment: I guess you mean `Dec 24, 2013`, right?

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: @h2ooooooo yes , how can i do that?

Comment: @ashuthinks I can't tell if you're trying to convert `Dec 24, 2013` to  `Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530` or `Tue Dec 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530` to `Dec 24, 2013`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this might help you. Further more refer this [document](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('M d, yy', 
new Date(),
{ monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul',
                  'Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'] 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JQuery Date Format Plugin](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat) or if you have more dates to work on your project [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

In pure **`Javascript`**,

There is no three digit format for default date in Javascript.  So create an array like

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

Once your is date is parsed, pass the `newDate` values as below

```
var con = monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ", " +   
                                                 newDate.getFullYear();
//returns Dec 24, 2013
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7eRXh/4/)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of phpjs you can atchieve this. Refer below url

[Phpjs date function](http://phpjs.org/functions/date/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`date.js`](http://www.datejs.com/)

There a method called [`toString`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString), it accepts some [`format specifiers`](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers).

Code:

```
var dateString = 'Dec 17, 2013'; // date string
var actualDate = new Date(dateString); // convert to actual date
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+7);
var newDate2 = newDate.toString("MMM d, yyyy");

alert(newDate2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MWQAE/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any extra js libs. Just native Javascript is enough.
Try

```
//Extend prototype so you can call it in any Date instance
Date.prototype.customFormat = function() {
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],t = this;
    return [months[t.getMonth() % 12], " ", t.getDate(), ", ", t.getFullYear()].join("")
}

//Now
alert((new Date).customFormat());
//7 days after
alert((new Date(+new Date + 7*24*3600*1000)).customFormat());
```